# How exactly does component set work and how am i supposed to pass values around to different functions in aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So i have one function which makes an apex call

```
     doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
                 
                       var Opptype =  component.get("v.simpleRecord.Type_Of_Opportunity__c");
     var action = component.get("c.getRecordTypeName");
                        action.setParams({
                    "OpportunityType" : Opptype
                });
                action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                      var quoteRecordId = response.getReturnValue();
                      component.set("v.quoteRecordValue", quoteRecordId);
console.log(component.get("v.quoteRecordValue");
console.log(component.get("v.quoteRecordId "); <--- both console logs return values
                    
               });
                     $A.enqueueAction(action);
        helper.showCreateRecordModal(component);
        }
```

now how exactly am i supposed to pass the value of quoteRecordId unto a helper function? Because on the helper when i use component.get("v.quoteRecordId"); i get undefined. Hell if i try to component.get that value afer the enqueueAction it's still undefined...

```
showCreateRecordModal : function(component) {

    component.get("v.quoteRecordValue");  <---undefined.
```

This is when i run console log

Edit: missed a copy paste

Comment: you have not defined the action. Define action with apex method name. and make sure you are getting value in `quoteRecordId`, by putting debug log.

Comment: looks like you have not used proper syntax for calling apex method from JS controller. Use var action = component.get("c.apexMethodName"); Please try to post your complete code including markup and apex controller

Comment: yeah i missed that part when adding copying the code over into the post, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the `action`. you need to define action with apex method name.

Ex.  `let action = component.get("c.getExpenses");`

Where `getExpenses` is the Name of Apex method.

You can refer this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_server)

Put the debug log and check you are getting value in `quoteRecordId` variable.

If you have to use `quoteRecordId` value in other function then you can save that value using component.set() method. else you can directly pass value to other function.

```
Controller
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
   var=quoteRecordId;
   helper.showCreateRecordModal(component,quoteRecordId);
}

Helper
showCreateRecordModal: function(component,quoteRecordId){
     console.log(quoteRecordId);
}
```

Comment: i missed that when copy --> pasting my code in. it's now defined.